# How to show a loading image in UWP?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I am developing an **UWP** application. When user clicks on any control, if that control is taking longer time to execute its tasks I want to show an indication to the user like **Operation is taking a long time, please wait** with Images on the center of the screen.
How can I do that in a UWP aplication?

I think here our UWP is working on Single Thread concept if I am right.
Please give me your suggestion to solve this issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best way to indicate a long running operation is to use the built-in `ProgressRing` control:

```
<ProgressRing x:Name="LoadingIndicator" />
```

Your long running operation should be implemented as an `async` method. You could call it as follows:

```
try
{
    LoadingIndicator.IsActive = true;
    await LongOperationAsync();
}
finally
{
    LoadingIndicator.IsActive = false;
}
```

Setting `IsActive` to `true` will display the progress ring and start the spinning. Setting it back to `false` will hide and deactivate it again. While `LongOperationAsync` is executing, the application will be responsive and the user will be able to interact with it.

If you're using MVVM, you can of course set a boolean property instead and bind it to `IsActive` property.

Not sure, where you've heard about a "single thread concept" for UWP apps, but nothing is stopping your app from being multithreaded. Indeed, you can't use the `Thread` class directly, but you should use `Task` instead anyway.

Comment: Thank you Now I am able to Do... @Damir Arh

Comment: how to set custom color for the progressring...By default it takes accent color...How to change it...

Comment: Just set the `Foreground` property, e.g.: `<ProgressRing x:Name="LoadingIndicator" Foreground="Yellow" />`

Answer (score 0):

You could use FFImageLoading it uses various methods for optimising image loading (including download/memory cache) and also supports loading / error placeholders:

`<ff:FFImage VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            TransformPlaceholders="False"
            LoadingPlaceholder="loading.png"
            ErrorPlaceholder="error.png"
            Height="500"
            Width="500"
            Source="http://loremflickr.com/600/600/nature?filename=simple.jpg">`